# When was ShellExecute introduced into the Windows API

Tags: windows, history

Anyone know for sure the date when the `ShellExecute` function was first introduced into the Windows API?

According to Wikipedia, Win32 was introduced with Windows NT (1993?) and shipped with Windows 95 (1995?), but I'm not for sure that Win32 included `ShellExecute` at this time.

I've been poking around the WWW and the earliest dated mention I've found of `ShellExecute` is from a blog post in 2002 called "introducing ShellExecute". Any history buffs out there? Does anyone keep track of this sort of thing?

Comment: Here's a 1997 reference: http://www.drdobbs.com/a-gotourl-function-using-shellexecute/184416463 ; here's an indication that `ShellExecute` was available under Windows 3.11: http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/4e83672e08a595cd.htm ("Yeah, this unique feature is that the Win16 ShellExecute function has 
problems with an URL that doesn't adhere to the 8.3 file naming 
convention"); I'm not yet able to find out when it turned up in Win16 so can't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version of Windows NT was [Windows NT 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_3.1).

From Microsoft's [KB224816](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816):

> The ShellExecute API is supported on Microsoft Windows 95 and Microsoft Windows NT 3.1 and later.

So ShellExecute existed in all versions of Windows NT.

Comment: Good quote. I have memory of it being available in Win95, but I couldn't state definitively if it was there the day it was released.